# What is a scalable way to simulate HASHBYTES using a SQL CLR scalar function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, etl, sql-clr, hashing

As part of our ETL process, we compare rows from staging against the reporting database to figure out if any of the columns have actually changed since the data was last loaded.

The comparison is based on the unique key of the table and some kind of hash of all of the other columns. We currently use [`HASHBYTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with the `SHA2_256` algorithm and have found that it does not scale on large servers if many concurrent worker threads are all calling `HASHBYTES`.

Throughput measured in hashes per second does not increase past 16 concurrent threads when testing on a 96 core server. I test by changing the number of concurrent `MAXDOP 8` queries from 1 - 12. Testing with `MAXDOP 1` showed the same scalability bottleneck.

As a workaround I want to try a SQL CLR solution. Here is my attempt to state the requirements:

- The function must be able to participate in parallel queries
- The function must be deterministic
- The function must take an input of an `NVARCHAR` or `VARBINARY` string (all relevant columns are concatenated together)
- The typical input size of the string will be 100 - 20000 characters in length. 20000 is not a max
- The chance of a hash collision should be roughly equal to or better than the MD5 algorithm. `CHECKSUM` does not work for us because there are too many collisions.
- The function must scale well on large servers (throughput per thread should not significantly decrease as the number of threads increases)

For Application Reasons™, assume that I cannot save off the value of the hash for the reporting table. It's a CCI which doesn't support triggers or computed columns (there are other problems as well that I don't want to get into).

What is a scalable way to simulate `HASHBYTES` using a SQL CLR function? My goal can be expressed as getting as many hashes per second as I can on a large server, so performance matters as well. I am terrible with CLR so I don't know how to accomplish this. If it motivates anyone to answer, I plan on adding a bounty to this question as soon as I am able. Below is an example query which very roughly illustrates the use case:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CHANGED_IDS;

SELECT stg.ID INTO #CHANGED_IDS
FROM (
    SELECT ID,
    CAST( HASHBYTES ('SHA2_256', 
        CAST(FK1 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK2 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK3 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK4 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK5 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK6 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK7 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK8 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK9 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK10 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK11 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK12 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK13 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK14 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK15 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(STR1 AS NVARCHAR(500)) +
        CAST(STR2 AS NVARCHAR(500)) +
        CAST(STR3 AS NVARCHAR(500)) +
        CAST(STR4 AS NVARCHAR(500)) +
        CAST(STR5 AS NVARCHAR(500)) +
        CAST(COMP1 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + 
        CAST(COMP2 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + 
        CAST(COMP3 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + 
        CAST(COMP4 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + 
        CAST(COMP5 AS NVARCHAR(1)))
     AS BINARY(32)) HASH1
    FROM HB_TBL WITH (TABLOCK)
) stg
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID,
    CAST(HASHBYTES ('SHA2_256', 
        CAST(FK1 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK2 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK3 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK4 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK5 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK6 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK7 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK8 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK9 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK10 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK11 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK12 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK13 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK14 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(FK15 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + 
        CAST(STR1 AS NVARCHAR(500)) +
        CAST(STR2 AS NVARCHAR(500)) +
        CAST(STR3 AS NVARCHAR(500)) +
        CAST(STR4 AS NVARCHAR(500)) +
        CAST(STR5 AS NVARCHAR(500)) +
        CAST(COMP1 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + 
        CAST(COMP2 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + 
        CAST(COMP3 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + 
        CAST(COMP4 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + 
        CAST(COMP5 AS NVARCHAR(1)) )
 AS BINARY(32)) HASH1
    FROM HB_TBL_2 WITH (TABLOCK)
) rpt ON rpt.ID = stg.ID
WHERE rpt.HASH1 <> stg.HASH1
OPTION (MAXDOP 8);
```

To simplify things a bit, I'll probably use something like the following for benchmarking. I'll post results with `HASHBYTES` on Monday:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.HASH_ME (
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK1 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK2 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK3 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK4 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK5 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK6 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK7 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK8 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK9 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK10 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK11 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK12 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK13 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK14 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK15 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    STR1 NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    STR2 NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    STR3 NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    STR4 NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    STR5 NVARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL,
    COMP1 TINYINT NOT NULL,
    COMP2 TINYINT NOT NULL,
    COMP3 TINYINT NOT NULL,
    COMP4 TINYINT NOT NULL,
    COMP5 TINYINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.HASH_ME WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT RN,
RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000,
RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000,
RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000, RN % 1000000,
REPLICATE(CHAR(65 + RN % 10 ), 30)
,REPLICATE(CHAR(65 + RN % 10 ), 30)
,REPLICATE(CHAR(65 + RN % 10 ), 30)
,REPLICATE(CHAR(65 + RN % 10 ), 30)
,REPLICATE(CHAR(65 + RN % 10 ), 1000),
0,1,0,1,0
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (100000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    FROM master..spt_values t1
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
) q
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

SELECT MAX(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',
CAST(N'' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK1 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK2 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK3 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK4 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK5 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK6 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK7 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK8 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK9 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK10 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK11 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK12 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK13 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK14 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(FK15 AS NVARCHAR(19)) + N'|' +
CAST(STR1 AS NVARCHAR(500)) + N'|' +
CAST(STR2 AS NVARCHAR(500)) + N'|' +
CAST(STR3 AS NVARCHAR(500)) + N'|' +
CAST(STR4 AS NVARCHAR(500)) + N'|' +
CAST(STR5 AS NVARCHAR(2000)) + N'|' +
CAST(COMP1 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + N'|' +
CAST(COMP2 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + N'|' +
CAST(COMP3 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + N'|' +
CAST(COMP4 AS NVARCHAR(1)) + N'|' +
CAST(COMP5 AS NVARCHAR(1)) )
)
FROM dbo.HASH_ME
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since you're just looking for changes, you don't need a cryptographic hash function.

You could choose from one of the faster non-cryptographic hashes in the open-source [Data.HashFunction library](https://github.com/brandondahler/Data.HashFunction#datahashfunction-) by Brandon Dahler, licensed under the permissive and OSI approved [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT). `SpookyHash` is a popular choice.

#### Example implementation

#### Source Code

```cs
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.HashFunction.SpookyHash;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction
        (
            DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None,
            SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None,
            IsDeterministic = true,
            IsPrecise = true
        )
    ]
    public static byte[] SpookyHash
        (
            [SqlFacet (MaxSize = 8000)]
            SqlBinary Input
        )
    {
        ISpookyHashV2 sh = SpookyHashV2Factory.Instance.Create();
        return sh.ComputeHash(Input.Value).Hash;
    }

    [SqlFunction
        (
            DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None,
            IsDeterministic = true,
            IsPrecise = true,
            SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None
        )
    ]
    public static byte[] SpookyHashLOB
        (
            [SqlFacet (MaxSize = -1)]
            SqlBinary Input
        )
    {
        ISpookyHashV2 sh = SpookyHashV2Factory.Instance.Create();
        return sh.ComputeHash(Input.Value).Hash;
    }
}
```

The source provides two functions, one for inputs of 8000 bytes or less, and a LOB version. The non-LOB version should be significantly quicker.

You might be able to wrap a LOB binary in [`COMPRESS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/compress-transact-sql) to get it under the 8000 byte limit, if that turns out to be worthwhile for performance. Alternatively, you could break the LOB up into sub-8000 byte segments, or simply reserve the use of `HASHBYTES` for the LOB case (since longer inputs scale better).

#### Pre-built code

You can obviously grab the package for yourself and compile everything, but I built the assemblies below to make quick testing easier:

https://gist.github.com/SQLKiwi/365b265b476bf86754457fc9514b2300

#### T-SQL functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SpookyHash
(
    @Input varbinary(8000)
)
RETURNS binary(16)
WITH 
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT, 
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS EXTERNAL NAME Spooky.UserDefinedFunctions.SpookyHash;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SpookyHashLOB
(
    @Input varbinary(max)
)
RETURNS binary(16)
WITH 
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT, 
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS EXTERNAL NAME Spooky.UserDefinedFunctions.SpookyHashLOB;
GO
```

#### Usage

An example use given the sample data in the question:

```
SELECT
    HT1.ID
FROM dbo.HB_TBL AS HT1
JOIN dbo.HB_TBL_2 AS HT2
    ON HT2.ID = HT1.ID
    AND dbo.SpookyHash
    (
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK1) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK2) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK3) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK4) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK5) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK6) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK7) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK8) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK9) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK10) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK11) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK12) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK13) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK14) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT2.FK15) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(varbinary(1000), HT2.STR1) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(varbinary(1000), HT2.STR2) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(varbinary(1000), HT2.STR3) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(varbinary(1000), HT2.STR4) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(varbinary(1000), HT2.STR5) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(1), HT2.COMP1) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(1), HT2.COMP2) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(1), HT2.COMP3) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(1), HT2.COMP4) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(1), HT2.COMP5)
    )
    <> dbo.SpookyHash
    (
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK1) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK2) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK3) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK4) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK5) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK6) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK7) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK8) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK9) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK10) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK11) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK12) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK13) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK14) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(8), HT1.FK15) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(varbinary(1000), HT1.STR1) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(varbinary(1000), HT1.STR2) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(varbinary(1000), HT1.STR3) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(varbinary(1000), HT1.STR4) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(varbinary(1000), HT1.STR5) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(1), HT1.COMP1) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(1), HT1.COMP2) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(1), HT1.COMP3) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(1), HT1.COMP4) + 0x7C +
        CONVERT(binary(1), HT1.COMP5)
    );
```

When using the LOB version, the first parameter should be cast or converted to `varbinary(max)`.

#### Execution plan

[image: plan]

---

### Safe Spooky

The *Data.HashFunction* library uses a number of CLR language features that are considered `UNSAFE` by SQL Server. It is possible to write a basic Spooky Hash compatible with `SAFE` status. An example I wrote based on [Jon Hanna's *SpookilySharp*](https://bitbucket.org/JonHanna/spookilysharp/src/master/) is below:

https://gist.github.com/SQLKiwi/7a5bb26b0bee56f6d28a1d26669ce8f2

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure if parallelism will be any / significantly better with SQLCLR. However, it is really easy to test since there is a hash function in the Free version of the [SQL#](https://sqlsharp.com/?ref=db_228792) SQLCLR library (which I wrote) called **Util_HashBinary**. Supported algorithms are: MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512.

It takes a `VARBINARY(MAX)` value as input, so you can either concatenate the string version of each field (as you are currently doing) and then convert to `VARBINARY(MAX)`, or you can go directly to `VARBINARY` for each column and concatenate the converted values (this might be faster since you aren't dealing with strings or the extra conversion from string to `VARBINARY`). Below is an example showing both of these options. It also shows the `HASHBYTES` function so you can see that the values are the same between it and **SQL#.Util_HashBinary**.

Please note that the hash results when concatenating the `VARBINARY` values won't match the hash results when concatenating the `NVARCHAR` values. This is because the binary form of the `INT` value "1" is 0x00000001, while the UTF-16LE (i.e. `NVARCHAR`) form of the `INT` value of "1" (in binary form since that is what a hashing function will operate on) is 0x3100.

```
SELECT so.[object_id],
       SQL#.Util_HashBinary(N'SHA256',
                            CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),
                                    CONCAT(so.[name], so.[schema_id], so.[create_date])
                                   )
                           ) AS [SQLCLR-ConcatStrings],
       HASHBYTES(N'SHA2_256',
                 CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),
                         CONCAT(so.[name], so.[schema_id], so.[create_date])
                        )
                ) AS [BuiltIn-ConcatStrings]
FROM sys.objects so;


SELECT so.[object_id],
       SQL#.Util_HashBinary(N'SHA256',
                            CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), so.[name]) + 
                            CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), so.[schema_id]) +
                            CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), so.[create_date])
                           ) AS [SQLCLR-ConcatVarBinaries],
       HASHBYTES(N'SHA2_256',
                 CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), so.[name]) + 
                 CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), so.[schema_id]) +
                 CONVERT(VARBINARY(500), so.[create_date])
                ) AS [BuiltIn-ConcatVarBinaries]
FROM sys.objects so;
```

You can test something more comparable to the non-LOB Spooky using:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [SQL#].[Util_HashBinary8k]
(@Algorithm [nvarchar](50), @BaseData [varbinary](8000))
RETURNS [varbinary](8000) 
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS EXTERNAL NAME [SQL#].[UTILITY].[HashBinary];
```

Note: **Util_HashBinary** uses the managed SHA256 algorithm that is built into .NET, and should not be using the "bcrypt" library.

Beyond that aspect of the question, there are some additional thoughts that might help this process:

### Additional Thought #1 (pre-calculate hashes, at least some)

You mentioned a few things:

1. > we compare rows from staging against the reporting database to figure out if any of the columns have actually changed since the data was last loaded.

   and:
2. > I cannot save off the value of the hash for the reporting table. It's a CCI which doesn't support triggers or computed columns

   and:
3. > the tables can be updated outside of the ETL process

It sounds like the data in this reporting table is stable for a period of time, and is only modified by this ETL process.

If nothing else modifies this table, then we really don't need a trigger or indexed view after all (I originally thought that you might).

Since you can't modify the schema of the reporting table, would it at least be possible to create a related table to contain the pre-calculated hash (and UTC time of when it was calculated)? This would allow you to have a pre-calculated value to compare against next time, leaving only the incoming value that requires calculating the hash of. This would reduce the number of calls to either `HASHBYTES` or `SQL#.Util_HashBinary` by half. You would simply join to this table of hashes during the import process.

You would also create a separate stored procedure that simply refreshes the hashes of this table. It just updates the hashes of any related row that has changed to be current, and updates the timestamp for those modified rows. This proc can/should be executed at the end of any other process that updates this table. It can also be scheduled to run 30 - 60 minutes prior to this ETL starting (depending on how long it takes to execute, and when any of these other processes might run). It can even be executed manually if you ever suspect there might be rows that are out of sync.

It was then noted that:

> there are over 500 tables

That many tables does make it more difficult to have an extra table per each to contain the current hashes, but this is not impossible as it could be scripted since it would be a standard schema. The scripting would just need to account for source table name and discovery of source table PK column(s).

Still, regardless of which hash algorithm ultimately proves to be the most scalable, I still *highly* recommend finding at least a few tables (perhaps there are some that are MUCH larger than the rest of the 500 tables) and setting up a related table to capture current hashes so the "current" values can be known prior to the ETL process. Even the fastest function can't out-perform never having to call it in the first place ;-).

### Additional Thought #2 (`VARBINARY` instead of `NVARCHAR`)

Regardless of SQLCLR vs built-in `HASHBYTES`, I would still recommend converting directly to `VARBINARY` as that *should* be faster. Concatenating strings is just not terribly efficient. *And*, that's in addition to converting non-string values into strings in the first place, which requires extra effort (I assume the amount of effort varies based on the base type: `DATETIME` requiring more than `BIGINT`), whereas converting to `VARBINARY` simply gives you the underlying value (in most cases).

And, in fact, testing the same dataset that the other tests used, and using `HASHBYTES(N'SHA2_256',...)`, showed a 23.415% increase in total hashes calculated in one minute. And that increase was for doing nothing more than using `VARBINARY` instead of `NVARCHAR`! 😸 (please see [community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/228966/30859) for details)

### Additional Thought #3 (be mindful of input parameters)

Further testing showed that one area that impacts performance (over this volume of executions) is input parameters: how many and what type(s).

The **Util_HashBinary** SQLCLR function that is currently in my SQL# library has two input parameters: one `VARBINARY` (the value to hash), and one `NVARCHAR` (the algorithm to use). This is due to my mirroring the signature of the `HASHBYTES` function. However, I found that if I removed the `NVARCHAR` parameter and created a function that only did SHA256, then performance improved quite nicely. I assume that even switching the `NVARCHAR` parameter to `INT` would have helped, but I also assume that not even having the extra `INT` parameter is at least *slightly* faster.

Also, `SqlBytes.Value` might perform better than `SqlBinary.Value`.

I created two new functions: **Util_HashSHA256Binary** and **Util_HashSHA256Binary8k** for this testing. These will be included in the next release of SQL# (no date set for that yet).

I also found that the testing methodology could be slightly improved, so I updated the test harness in the community wiki answer below to include:

1. pre-loading of the SQLCLR assemblies to ensure that the load time overhead doesn't skew the results.
2. a verification procedure to check for collisions. If any are found, it displays the number of unique/distinct rows and the total number of rows. This allows one to determine if the number of collisions (if there are any) is beyond the limit for the given use case. Some use cases might allows for a small number of collisions, others might require none. A super-fast function is useless if it can't detect changes to the desired level of accuracy. For example, using the test harness provided by the O.P., I increased the row count to 100k rows (it was originally 10k) and found that `CHECKSUM` registered over 9k collisions, which is 9% (yikes).

### Additional Thought #4 (`HASHBYTES` + SQLCLR together?)

Depending on where the bottleneck is, it might even help to use a combination of built-in `HASHBYTES` and a SQLCLR UDF to do the same hash. If built-in functions are constrained differently / separately from SQLCLR operations, then this approach might be able to accomplish more concurrently than either `HASHBYTES` or SQLCLR individually. It's definitely worth testing.

### Additional Thought #5 (hashing object caching?)

The caching of the hashing algorithm object as suggested in [David Browne's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/229282/30859) certainly seems interesting, so I tried it and found the following two points of interest:

1. For whatever reason, it does not seem to provide much, if any, performance improvement. I could have done something incorrectly, but here is what I tried:

   ```
   static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, SHA256Managed> hashers =
       new ConcurrentDictionary<int, SHA256Managed>();

   [return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = 100)]
   [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true)]
   public static SqlBinary FastHash([SqlFacet(MaxSize = 1000)] SqlBytes Input)
   {
       SHA256Managed sh = hashers.GetOrAdd(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                                           i => new SHA256Managed());

       return sh.ComputeHash(Input.Value);
   }
   ```
2. The `ManagedThreadId` value appears to be the same for all SQLCLR references in a particular query. I tested multiple references to the same function, as well as a reference to a different function, all 3 being given different input values, and returning different (but expected) return values. For both test functions, the output was a string that included the `ManagedThreadId` as well as a string representation of the hash result. The `ManagedThreadId` value was the same for all UDF references in the query, and across all rows. But, the hash result was the same for the same input string and different for different input strings.

   While I didn't see any erroneous results in my testing, wouldn't this increase the chances of a race condition? If the key of the dictionary is the same for all SQLCLR objects called in a particular query, then they would be sharing the same value or object stored for that key, right? The point being, even thought it seemed to work here (to a degree, again there did not seem to be much performance gain, but functionally nothing broke), that doesn't give me confidence that this approach will work in other scenarios.

Answer (score 12):

This isn't a traditional answer, but I thought it would be helpful to post benchmarks of some of the techniques mentioned so far. I'm testing on a 96 core server with SQL Server 2017 CU9.

Many scalability problems are caused by concurrent threads contending over some global state. For example, consider classic PFS page contention. This can happen if too many worker threads need to modify the same page in memory. As code becomes more efficient it may request the latch faster. That increases contention. To put it simply, efficient code is more likely to lead to scalability issues because the global state is contended over more severely. Slow code is less likely to cause scalability issues because the global state isn't accessed as frequently.

`HASHBYTES` scalability is partially based on the length of the input string. My theory was to why this occurs is that access to some global state is needed when the `HASHBYTES` function is called. The easy global state to observe is a memory page needs to be allocated per call on some versions of SQL Server. The harder one to observe is that there's some kind of OS contention. As a result, if `HASHBYTES` is called by the code less frequently then contention goes down. One way to reduce the rate of `HASHBYTES` calls is to increase the amount of hashing work needed per call. Hashing work is partially based on the length of the input string. To reproduce the scalability problem I saw in the application I needed to change the demo data. A reasonable worst case scenario is a table with 21 `BIGINT` columns. The definition of the table is included in the code at the bottom. To reduce Local Factors™, I'm using concurrent `MAXDOP 1` queries that operate on relatively small tables. My quick benchmark code is at the bottom.

Note the functions return different hash lengths. `MD5` and `SpookyHash` are both 128 bit hashes, `SHA256` is a 256 bit hash.

### RESULTS (`NVARCHAR` vs `VARBINARY` conversion and concatenation)

In order to see if converting to, and concatenating, `VARBINARY` is truly more efficient / performant than `NVARCHAR`, an `NVARCHAR` version of the `RUN_HASHBYTES_SHA2_256` stored procedure was created from the same template (see "Step 5" in **BENCHMARKING CODE** section below). The only differences are:

1. Stored Procedure name ends in `_NVC`
2. `BINARY(8)` for the `CAST` function was changed to be `NVARCHAR(15)`
3. `0x7C` was changed to be `N'|'`

Resulting in:

```
CAST(FK1 AS NVARCHAR(15)) + N'|' +
```

instead of:

```
CAST(FK1 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
```

The table below contains the number of hashes performed in 1 minute. The tests were performed on a different server than was used for the other tests noted below.

```
╔════════════════╦══════════╦══════════════╗
║    Datatype    ║  Test #  ║ Total Hashes ║
╠════════════════╬══════════╬══════════════╣
║ NVARCHAR       ║        1 ║     10200000 ║
║ NVARCHAR       ║        2 ║     10300000 ║
║ NVARCHAR       ║  AVERAGE ║ * 10250000 * ║
║ -------------- ║ -------- ║ ------------ ║
║ VARBINARY      ║        1 ║     12500000 ║
║ VARBINARY      ║        2 ║     12800000 ║
║ VARBINARY      ║  AVERAGE ║ * 12650000 * ║
╚════════════════╩══════════╩══════════════╝
```

Looking at just the averages, we can calculate the benefit of switching to `VARBINARY`:

```
SELECT (12650000 - 10250000) AS [IncreaseAmount],
       ROUND(((126500000 - 10250000) / 10250000) * 100.0, 3) AS [IncreasePercentage]
```

That returns:

```
IncreaseAmount:    2400000.0
IncreasePercentage:   23.415
```

### RESULTS (hash algorithms and implementations)

The table below contains the number of hashes performed in 1 minute. For example, using `CHECKSUM` with 84 concurrent queries resulted in over 2 billion hashes being performed before time ran out.

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║      Function      ║ 12 threads ║ 48 threads ║ 84 threads ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ CHECKSUM           ║  281250000 ║ 1122440000 ║ 2040100000 ║
║ HASHBYTES MD5      ║   75940000 ║  106190000 ║  112750000 ║
║ HASHBYTES SHA2_256 ║   80210000 ║  117080000 ║  124790000 ║
║ CLR Spooky         ║  131250000 ║  505700000 ║  786150000 ║
║ CLR SpookyLOB      ║   17420000 ║   27160000 ║   31380000 ║
║ SQL# MD5           ║   17080000 ║   26450000 ║   29080000 ║
║ SQL# SHA2_256      ║   18370000 ║   28860000 ║   32590000 ║
║ SQL# MD5 8k        ║   24440000 ║   30560000 ║   32550000 ║
║ SQL# SHA2_256 8k   ║   87240000 ║  159310000 ║  155760000 ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

If you prefer to see the same numbers measured in terms of work per thread-second:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║      Function      ║ 12 threads per core-second ║ 48 threads per core-second ║ 84 threads per core-second ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║ CHECKSUM           ║                     390625 ║                     389736 ║                     404782 ║
║ HASHBYTES MD5      ║                     105472 ║                      36872 ║                      22371 ║
║ HASHBYTES SHA2_256 ║                     111403 ║                      40653 ║                      24760 ║
║ CLR Spooky         ║                     182292 ║                     175590 ║                     155982 ║
║ CLR SpookyLOB      ║                      24194 ║                       9431 ║                       6226 ║
║ SQL# MD5           ║                      23722 ║                       9184 ║                       5770 ║
║ SQL# SHA2_256      ║                      25514 ║                      10021 ║                       6466 ║
║ SQL# MD5 8k        ║                      33944 ║                      10611 ║                       6458 ║
║ SQL# SHA2_256 8k   ║                     121167 ║                      55316 ║                      30905 ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Some quick thoughts on all of the methods:

- `CHECKSUM`: very good scalability as expected
- `HASHBYTES`: scalability issues include one memory allocation per call and a large amount of CPU spent in the OS
- `Spooky`: surprisingly good scalability
- `Spooky LOB`: the spinlock `SOS_SELIST_SIZED_SLOCK` spins out of control. I suspect this is a general issue with passing LOBs through CLR functions, but I'm not sure
- `Util_HashBinary`: looks like it gets hit by the same spinlock. I haven't looked into this so far because there's probably not a lot that I can do about it:

[image: spin your lock]

- `Util_HashBinary 8k`: very surprising results, not sure what's going on here

**Final results tested on a smaller server:**

```
╔═════════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦════════════════════════╗
║     Hash Algorithm      ║ Hashes over 11 threads ║ Hashes over 44 threads ║
╠═════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ HASHBYTES SHA2_256      ║               85220000 ║              167050000 ║
║ SpookyHash              ║              101200000 ║              239530000 ║
║ Util_HashSHA256Binary8k ║               90590000 ║              217170000 ║
║ SpookyHashLOB           ║               23490000 ║               38370000 ║
║ Util_HashSHA256Binary   ║               23430000 ║               36590000 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

### BENCHMARKING CODE

**SETUP 1: Tables and Data**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.HASH_SMALL;

CREATE TABLE dbo.HASH_SMALL (
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK1 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK2 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK3 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK4 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK5 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK6 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK7 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK8 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK9 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK10 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK11 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK12 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK13 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK14 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK15 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK16 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK17 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK18 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK19 BIGINT NOT NULL,
    FK20 BIGINT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.HASH_SMALL WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT RN,
4000000 - RN, 4000000 - RN
,200000000 - RN, 200000000 - RN
, RN % 500000 , RN % 500000 , RN % 500000
, RN % 500000 , RN % 500000 , RN % 500000 
, 100000 - RN % 100000, RN % 100000
, 100000 - RN % 100000, RN % 100000
, 100000 - RN % 100000, RN % 100000
, 100000 - RN % 100000, RN % 100000
, 100000 - RN % 100000, RN % 100000
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (10000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
    FROM master..spt_values t1
    CROSS JOIN master..spt_values t2
) q
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.LOG_HASHES;
CREATE TABLE dbo.LOG_HASHES (
LOG_TIME DATETIME,
HASH_ALGORITHM INT,
SESSION_ID INT,
NUM_HASHES BIGINT
);
```

**SETUP 2: Master Execution Proc**

```
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE (@HashAlgorithm INT)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @target_end_time DATETIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, GETDATE()),
        @query_execution_count INT = 0;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ProcName NVARCHAR(261); -- schema_name + proc_name + '[].[]'

DECLARE @RowCount INT;
SELECT @RowCount = SUM(prtn.[row_count])
FROM   sys.dm_db_partition_stats prtn
WHERE  prtn.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.HASH_SMALL')
AND    prtn.[index_id] < 2;


-- Load assembly if not loaded to prevent load time from skewing results
DECLARE @OptionalInitSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @OptionalInitSQL = CASE @HashAlgorithm
       WHEN 1 THEN N'SELECT @Dummy = dbo.SpookyHash(0x1234);'
       WHEN 2 THEN N'' -- HASHBYTES
       WHEN 3 THEN N'' -- HASHBYTES
       WHEN 4 THEN N'' -- CHECKSUM
       WHEN 5 THEN N'SELECT @Dummy = dbo.SpookyHashLOB(0x1234);'
       WHEN 6 THEN N'SELECT @Dummy = SQL#.Util_HashBinary(N''MD5'', 0x1234);'
       WHEN 7 THEN N'SELECT @Dummy = SQL#.Util_HashBinary(N''SHA256'', 0x1234);'
       WHEN 8 THEN N'SELECT @Dummy = SQL#.Util_HashBinary8k(N''MD5'', 0x1234);'
       WHEN 9 THEN N'SELECT @Dummy = SQL#.Util_HashBinary8k(N''SHA256'', 0x1234);'
/* -- BETA / non-public code
       WHEN 10 THEN N'SELECT @Dummy = SQL#.Util_HashSHA256Binary8k(0x1234);'
       WHEN 11 THEN N'SELECT @Dummy = SQL#.Util_HashSHA256Binary(0x1234);'
*/
   END;


IF (RTRIM(@OptionalInitSQL) <> N'')
BEGIN
    SET @OptionalInitSQL = N'
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Dummy VARBINARY(100);
' + @OptionalInitSQL;

    RAISERROR(N'** Executing optional initialization code:', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    RAISERROR(@OptionalInitSQL, 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    EXEC (@OptionalInitSQL);
    RAISERROR(N'-------------------------------------------', 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
END;


SET @ProcName = CASE @HashAlgorithm
                    WHEN 1 THEN N'dbo.RUN_SpookyHash'
                    WHEN 2 THEN N'dbo.RUN_HASHBYTES_MD5'
                    WHEN 3 THEN N'dbo.RUN_HASHBYTES_SHA2_256'
                    WHEN 4 THEN N'dbo.RUN_CHECKSUM'
                    WHEN 5 THEN N'dbo.RUN_SpookyHashLOB'
                    WHEN 6 THEN N'dbo.RUN_SR_MD5'
                    WHEN 7 THEN N'dbo.RUN_SR_SHA256'
                    WHEN 8 THEN N'dbo.RUN_SR_MD5_8k'
                    WHEN 9 THEN N'dbo.RUN_SR_SHA256_8k'
/* -- BETA / non-public code
                    WHEN 10 THEN N'dbo.RUN_SR_SHA256_new'
                    WHEN 11 THEN N'dbo.RUN_SR_SHA256LOB_new'
*/
                    WHEN 13 THEN N'dbo.RUN_HASHBYTES_SHA2_256_NVC'
                END;

RAISERROR(N'** Executing proc: %s', 10, 1, @ProcName) WITH NOWAIT;

WHILE GETDATE() < @target_end_time
BEGIN
    EXEC @ProcName;

    SET @query_execution_count = @query_execution_count + 1;
END;

INSERT INTO dbo.LOG_HASHES
VALUES (GETDATE(), @HashAlgorithm, @@SPID, @RowCount * @query_execution_count);

END;
GO
```

**SETUP 3: Collision Detection Proc**

```
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS (@HashAlgorithm INT)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @RowCount INT;
SELECT @RowCount = SUM(prtn.[row_count])
FROM   sys.dm_db_partition_stats prtn
WHERE  prtn.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.HASH_SMALL')
AND    prtn.[index_id] < 2;


DECLARE @CollisionTestRows INT;
DECLARE @CollisionTestSQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @CollisionTestSQL = N'
SELECT @RowsOut = COUNT(DISTINCT '
+ CASE @HashAlgorithm
       WHEN 1 THEN N'dbo.SpookyHash('
       WHEN 2 THEN N'HASHBYTES(''MD5'','
       WHEN 3 THEN N'HASHBYTES(''SHA2_256'','
       WHEN 4 THEN N'CHECKSUM('
       WHEN 5 THEN N'dbo.SpookyHashLOB('
       WHEN 6 THEN N'SQL#.Util_HashBinary(N''MD5'','
       WHEN 7 THEN N'SQL#.Util_HashBinary(N''SHA256'','
       WHEN 8 THEN N'SQL#.[Util_HashBinary8k](N''MD5'','
       WHEN 9 THEN N'SQL#.[Util_HashBinary8k](N''SHA256'','
--/* -- BETA / non-public code
       WHEN 10 THEN N'SQL#.[Util_HashSHA256Binary8k]('
       WHEN 11 THEN N'SQL#.[Util_HashSHA256Binary]('
--*/
   END
+ N'
    CAST(FK1 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK2 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK3 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK4 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK5 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK6 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK7 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK8 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK9 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK10 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK11 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK12 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK13 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK14 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK15 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK16 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK17 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK18 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK19 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK20 AS BINARY(8))  ))
FROM dbo.HASH_SMALL;';

PRINT @CollisionTestSQL;

EXEC sp_executesql
  @CollisionTestSQL,
  N'@RowsOut INT OUTPUT',
  @RowsOut = @CollisionTestRows OUTPUT;


IF (@CollisionTestRows <> @RowCount)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Collisions for algorithm: %d!!!  %d unique rows out of %d.',
    16, 1, @HashAlgorithm, @CollisionTestRows, @RowCount);
END;
GO
```

**SETUP 4: Cleanup (DROP All Test Procs)**

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
SELECT @SQL += N'DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].' + QUOTENAME(sp.[name])
            + N';' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)
FROM  sys.objects sp
WHERE sp.[name] LIKE N'RUN[_]%'
AND   sp.[type_desc] = N'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
AND   sp.[name] <> N'RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE'

PRINT @SQL;

EXEC (@SQL);
```

**SETUP 5: Generate Test Procs**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TestProcsToCreate TABLE
(
  ProcName sysname NOT NULL,
  CodeToExec NVARCHAR(261) NOT NULL
);
DECLARE @ProcName sysname,
        @CodeToExec NVARCHAR(261);

INSERT INTO @TestProcsToCreate VALUES
  (N'SpookyHash', N'dbo.SpookyHash('),
  (N'HASHBYTES_MD5', N'HASHBYTES(''MD5'','),
  (N'HASHBYTES_SHA2_256', N'HASHBYTES(''SHA2_256'','),
  (N'CHECKSUM', N'CHECKSUM('),
  (N'SpookyHashLOB', N'dbo.SpookyHashLOB('),
  (N'SR_MD5', N'SQL#.Util_HashBinary(N''MD5'','),
  (N'SR_SHA256', N'SQL#.Util_HashBinary(N''SHA256'','),
  (N'SR_MD5_8k', N'SQL#.[Util_HashBinary8k](N''MD5'','),
  (N'SR_SHA256_8k', N'SQL#.[Util_HashBinary8k](N''SHA256'',')
--/* -- BETA / non-public code
  , (N'SR_SHA256_new', N'SQL#.[Util_HashSHA256Binary8k]('),
  (N'SR_SHA256LOB_new', N'SQL#.[Util_HashSHA256Binary](');
--*/
DECLARE @ProcTemplate NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @ProcToCreate NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @ProcTemplate = N'
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.RUN_{{ProcName}}
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @dummy INT;
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @dummy = COUNT({{CodeToExec}}
    CAST(FK1 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK2 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK3 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK4 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK5 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK6 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK7 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK8 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK9 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK10 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK11 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK12 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK13 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK14 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK15 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK16 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK17 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK18 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK19 AS BINARY(8)) + 0x7C +
    CAST(FK20 AS BINARY(8)) 
    )
    )
    FROM dbo.HASH_SMALL
    OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

END;
';

DECLARE CreateProcsCurs CURSOR READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT [ProcName], [CodeToExec]
    FROM @TestProcsToCreate;

OPEN [CreateProcsCurs];

FETCH NEXT
FROM  [CreateProcsCurs]
INTO  @ProcName, @CodeToExec;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    -- First: create VARBINARY version
    SET @ProcToCreate = REPLACE(REPLACE(@ProcTemplate,
                                        N'{{ProcName}}',
                                        @ProcName),
                                N'{{CodeToExec}}',
                                @CodeToExec);

    EXEC (@ProcToCreate);

    -- Second: create NVARCHAR version (optional: built-ins only)
    IF (CHARINDEX(N'.', @CodeToExec) = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @ProcToCreate = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ProcToCreate,
                                                    N'dbo.RUN_' + @ProcName,
                                                    N'dbo.RUN_' + @ProcName + N'_NVC'),
                                            N'BINARY(8)',
                                            N'NVARCHAR(15)'),
                                    N'0x7C',
                                    N'N''|''');

        EXEC (@ProcToCreate);
    END;

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM  [CreateProcsCurs]
    INTO  @ProcName, @CodeToExec;
END;

CLOSE [CreateProcsCurs];
DEALLOCATE [CreateProcsCurs];
```

**TEST 1: Check For Collisions**

```
EXEC dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS 1;
EXEC dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS 2;
EXEC dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS 3;
EXEC dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS 4;
EXEC dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS 5;
EXEC dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS 6;
EXEC dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS 7;
EXEC dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS 8;
EXEC dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS 9;
EXEC dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS 10;
EXEC dbo.VERIFY_NO_COLLISIONS 11;
```

**TEST 2: Run Performance Tests**

```
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 1;
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 2;
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 3; -- HASHBYTES('SHA2_256'
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 4;
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 5;
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 6;
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 7;
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 8;
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 9;
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 10;
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 11;
EXEC dbo.RUN_HASHES_FOR_ONE_MINUTE 13; -- NVC version of #3


SELECT *
FROM   dbo.LOG_HASHES
ORDER BY [LOG_TIME] DESC;
```

### VALIDATION ISSUES TO RESOLVE

While focusing on the performance testing of a singular SQLCLR UDF, two issues that were discussed early on were not incorporated into the tests, but ideally should be investigated in order to determine which approach meets *all* of the requirements.

1. The function will be executed twice per each query (once for the import row, and once for the current row). The tests so far have only referenced the UDF one time in the test queries. This factor might not change the ranking of the options, but it shouldn't be ignored, just in case.
2. In a comment that has since been deleted, Paul White had mentioned:

   > One downside of replacing `HASHBYTES` with a CLR scalar function - it appears that CLR functions cannot use batch mode whereas `HASHBYTES` can. That might be important, performance-wise.

   So that is something to consider, and clearly requires testing. If the SQLCLR options do not provide any benefit over the built-in `HASHBYTES`, then that adds weight to [Solomon's suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/228792/30859) of capturing existing hashes (for at least the largest tables) into related tables.

Answer (score 7):

You can probably improve the performance, and perhaps the scalability of all the .NET approaches by pooling and caching any objects created in the function call.  EG for Paul White's code above:

```
static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int,ISpookyHashV2> hashers = new ConcurrentDictonary<ISpookyHashV2>()
public static byte[] SpookyHash([SqlFacet (MaxSize = 8000)] SqlBinary Input)
{
    ISpookyHashV2 sh = hashers.GetOrAdd(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i => SpookyHashV2Factory.Instance.Create());

    return sh.ComputeHash(Input.Value).Hash;
}
```

SQL CLR discourages and tries to prevent using static/shared variables, but it will let you use shared variables if you mark them as readonly.  Which, of course, is meaningless as you can just assign a single instance of some mutable type, like `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: interesting...is this thread safe if it is using the same instance over and over again? I know that the managed hashes have a `Clear()` method but I haven't looked that far into Spooky.

Comment: As @SolomonRutzky knows, I've always disliked this idea of putting mutable things in `static readonly`. It seems safe due to the `ManagedThreadId` but it gives me the eeby-jeebies anyway. The performance/concurrency improvement would have to be very significant for me to choose to do this. The Host does try to prevent people doing silly things with statics, but these are [roadhumps rather than absolute barriers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cbrumme/2004/02/21/hosting/). I prefer a flat track 

Comment: @PaulWhite and David. I could've done something wrong, or it could be a difference between `SHA256Managed` and `SpookyHashV2`, but I tried this and did not see much, if any, performance improvement. I also noticed that the `ManagedThreadId` value is the same for all SQLCLR references in a particular query. I tested multiple references to the same function, as well as a reference to a different function, all 3 being given different input values, and returning different (but expected) return values. Wouldn't this increase the chances of a race condition? To be fair, in my test I didn't see any.